# How can I run the spring boot application using services tabs on Intellij?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, war

I have built project using gradle. Built file is war file. The app can be run successfully by "java -jar xxxx.war" this command. I'd like to run this app locally on Intellij. The frontend is jsp. Because when run the app on Intellij, it doesn't include jsp, it doesn't work on services, I think.
Am I right? How can I run the app locally on the Intellij? I share the build.gradle file.
[image]
[image]

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'war'
}

jar { enabled = false }
bootJar { enabled = true }
bootRun {enabled = true}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compile.exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
```

Comment: Does it work in the command line if you run it via `gradle bootRun`? Your app may be not configured correctly if it doesn't work in this mode. If the war file works, you can use Tomcat run configuration and deploy this war file as an external source artifact.

Comment: `gradle bootRun` doesn't work. To correct configuration, what can I do? or what do you think I should share? As I know, spring boot uses embedded tomcat server so that I don't need to install tomcat on local.

Comment: I would check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp. It should work with `bootRun` and from the standalone Tomcat server if configured correctly.

Comment: I wanted to get real time updated view on browser as soon as I changed the source code. Through the above url, I knew JAR packaging is not an option if we are using JSP with Spring Boot. So war file is essential needed and should be deployed to tomcat container. And run by tomcat. This is the unique way to run my app. right?

Comment: If I run the `gradle bootRun` on the classpath of the project, the terminal shows the error. 
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'moyamo-admin'.
> Could not find method bootJar() for arguments [build_cyvu7040qathk0htgxk04d9hn$_run_closure2@321cd7a] on root project 'moyamo-admin' of type org.gradle.api.Project.